# Java Notarization of libAppleScriptEngine.dylib failing with The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK

Tags: java, macos, applescript, java-11, notarize

End of 2019 I had basic notarization of my Java 8 application working, on February 2020 Apple tightened the rules regarding notarization and this stopped my application from being notarized. Since I needed to move to Java 11 anyway I switched to Java 11 as I understood that this could be notarized ok and made necessary code changes but still having some problems.

Specifically there is an option in my application to communicate with *Apple Music* app (formerly iTunes) using Applescript to communicate with it. Prior to Java 11 this has always been possible via use of libAppleScriptEngine.dylib that comes with MacoS JDK/JRE and applescript jar (originally provided by Apple and provides interface so can be looked up by javax.scripting).

In Java 11 libAppleScriptEngine.dylib has been removed as documented in [Oracle JDK 11 Migration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-C25E2B1D-6C24-4403-8540-CFEA875B994A), with no replacement offered.

> Removed AppleScript Engine
>
> The AppleScript engine, a platform-specific javax.script
>   implementation, has been removed without any replacement in the JDK.
>
> The AppleScript engine has been mostly unusable in recent releases.
>   The functionality worked only in JDK 7 or JDK 8 on systems that
>   already had Apple's version of the AppleScriptEngine.jar file on the
>   system.

However, if I deploy my application with libAppleScriptEngine.dylib in the MacOS folder of my package the applescript continues to work fine running on Java 11.

But unfortunately (although signing verification of the app gives no error) notarization fails with following error

```
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "224840dd-15ec-45a2-8cd0-b046dab3bccb",
  "status": "Invalid",
  "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
  "statusCode": 4000,
  "archiveFilename": "songkong-osx.dmg",
  "uploadDate": "2020-04-14T11:50:17Z",
  "sha256": "b4d3a808a11a342b748901e5b6df5d628fb76a936ebe67ed5b2558cee5f268f7",
  "ticketContents": null,
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "songkong-osx.dmg/SongKong.app/Contents/MacOS/libAppleScriptEngine.dylib",
      "message": "The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    }
  ]
}
```

So is there a way round this ?

This is the end of the build script

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
/usr/bin/codesign --timestamp --options runtime \
     --entitlements /Users/paul/code/jthink/songkong/songkong.entitlements \
     --sign "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" \
     --force --deep --verbose /Applications/SongKong.app
/usr/bin/codesign -vvv --deep --strict /Applications/SongKong.app
spctl -a -t exec -vv /Applications/SongKong.app
cd /Users/paul/code/jthink/SongKong
/usr/local/bin/dmgcanvas /Users/paul/code/jthink/SongKong \
    /dmgCanvas_songkong.dmgCanvas /Users/paul/songkong-osx.dmg \
   -v SongKong -identity "Developer ID Application: P Taylor"\
   -notarizationAppleID paultaylor@jthink.net \
   -notarizationPassword password -notarizationPrimaryBundleID songkong
```

I tried replacing the version of libAppleScriptEngine.dylib with one from the latest Oracle Java 8 build  **Oracle 8u241** but made no differcne. I am surprised it is built against the old sdk, because I had heard it was now possible to notarize a Java 8 build.

Can I elect not to sign the libAppleScriptEngine.dylib file in order to allow notarization to succeed ?

Comment: Notarization only works for binaries linked against macOS 10.9 or later.

Comment: Any unsigned binary is also not going to notarize.

Comment: @RichardBarber I get that, but if 8u241 was only released fairly recently why does it contain libraries built against the very old OSX 10.9, and sicne I cant rebuilt the binary myself is there any way round this.

Comment: Java8 itself is built on the 10.7.5 sdk. That it is a recent update of Java8 you are using does not change that backwards compatibility. Java8 was originally released during 10.9 Mavericks and was compatible with the then-still-supported 10.7.5 Lion. Any update of Java8 is intended to support Mountain Lion and was linked against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Oracle Java 8 is linked to OSX 10.8.3, it will not pass Apple notary.

- The open-source ***Liberica*** JDK 8u252 https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-8u252/ is built for OSX 10.9, so that will work.  The release notes are in error, stating the minimum macOS version is 11.8, which does not exist.

`otool -l Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-jdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libAppleScriptEngine.dylib`  reports:

```
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.9
      sdk 10.14
```

---

There is no work-around which allows an **Oracle Java 8** binary to be notarized.

#### Notarization only works for binaries linked against macOS 10.9 or later.

- Java 8 itself is built on the 10.7.5 sdk. That it is a recent update of Java8 you are using does not change that backwards compatibility. Java 8 was originally released during 10.9 Mavericks and was compatible with the then-still-supported 10.7.5 Lion. Any update of Java 8 is intended to support 10.7.5 Lion and was linked against it.
- Java 9, released during 10.12 Sierra is backwards compatible to 10.10.

#### Any unsigned binary executable is also not going to notarize.

Comment: You temporarily got my hopes up but unfortunately libAppleScriptEngine.dylib is removed in Java 9 as well. So macOS is developed by Apple, Java is developed by Oracle. Many people still use Java 8 and Apple require  all new apps to be notarized so I don't understand why Oracle is still building new versions of Java 8, but building them against a defunct MacOS (10.7) it makes no sense.

Comment: So as it currently stands I have three choices, remove my use of Applescript and work out a different way of communicating with MacOS Music (no idea how to do this), remove support for Music App - bad for customers, not notarize application - bad for customers.

Comment: Okay I have a solution using libAppleScriptEngine,dylib from BellSoft Java 8u252 https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-8u252/ passes notarization and works.

Comment: Interesting, answer edited.  It is linked to 10.9 according to `otool -l` so that indeed should work for you.  Also note that it is open source, so you can certainly build it locally.